# google maps, adding click event to anchors to open info windows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application using Google maps, currently I have a number of markers added to the page and clicking on them opens up a info window.

I also have a pagniated list of results which I would like to open the corresponding info window when clicked. Currently clicking on one of these anchors opens all of the info windows, but this is as far as I can get currently.

I have a position marker function:

```
positionMarkers: function(lat, lng, user) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map
    });
    if (caption == null) {
        var caption = 'No caption available';
        } else {
        var caption = caption.text;
    }
    var contentString = '<div class="infoWindow"><h2>' + user + '</h2></div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 284
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    $('.instaframe').bind('click', function(){
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

The trouble I am having is with the bind function towards the end of the snippet. I am not sure where to go to bind the click event with just the marker being added each time the positionMarkers function runs.

```
<a href="#" class="instaframe">Marker one</a>
<a href="#" class="instaframe">Marker two</a>
<a href="#" class="instaframe">Marker three</a>
```

Help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Do you need only one infowindow open at a time or multiple?

Comment: Presumably you have multiple elements with the `instaframe` class. You're associating all of them with each infowindow as you create it.  So clicking on anything of that class will open all the infowindows.  You need to find a way to associate each infowindow with only one anchor.

Comment: @alkis, yes just the one open at a time.

Comment: @duncan, yes I am aware of this. I was just posting as much as I could get my head around for now. I got to the point where I can attach an event to all instances of instaframe to open all of them, however I am struggling to match them up with the correct info window

Comment: If you want only one infowindow visible then you must have only one infowindow in total. Create it outside your function (so it has the scope to be seen) and just change its content and open it on the marker you want. If you do that you will have the first step, only one infowindow visible. As for the second thing you want, well, you have to distinguish the element being clicked somehow. I would need to see some html before I can be more helpful.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your previous comment. The way the infowindows are currently is not an issue, this is the desired effect. Clicking on the markers works as required too. I have added the html for the anchors which I would like to trigger the info windows for that specific marker to open.

Comment: As I said. You must make your link tags distinguishable from one another. Consider using the data attribute, a fake class (just for identification) or even id.

Comment: [example (ported to the v3 API from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html) - [example with markes defined by XML (ported to the v3 API from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html). Don't use jquery.